# SQl: Group by month and year

Tags: asp.net, sql

Hi my code doesn't work, Im trying to group my blogentries by year and month here's my sql

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT WP_BlogEntries.BlogEntryID, WP_BlogEntries.AddedDate,
        WP_BlogEntries.AddedBy, WP_BlogEntries.BlogID, 
        WP_BlogEntries.Title, WP_BlogEntries.Description, WP_BlogEntries.Body,
        WP_BlogEntries.ReleaseDate, WP_BlogEntries.ExpireDate,
        WP_BlogEntries.Approved, WP_BlogEntries.Listed,
        WP_BlogEntries.CommentsEnabled, WP_BlogEntries.OnlyForMembers,
        WP_BlogEntries.ViewCount, WP_BlogEntries.Votes, 
        WP_BlogEntries.TotalRating
    FROM WP_BlogEntries
    WHERE WP_BlogEntries.ReleaseDate < GETDATE()
        AND WP_BlogEntries.ExpireDate > GETDATE()
        AND Approved = 1
        AND Listed = 1
        AND WP_BlogEntries.BlogID = @BlogID) MonthEntries 
    GROUP BY YEAR(ReleaseDate), MONTH(ReleaseDate)
```

Comment: simply stating "my code doesn't work" isn't very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know the error message.

You can't do a `SELECT * FROM` if you specify `GROUP BY`.

The only valid columns are those in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function.

If you group by year and month, then each row will contain one year and month, it is impossible for SQL to know which other columns to display as there could be more than one. (e.g. two blog entries in one month)

Did you mean to `ORDER BY` instead?

Comment: I want to create a list in asp.net of the year and then the months a blog entry was entered

Comment: Would I use DISTINCT in the statement

Comment: `SELECT YEAR(ReleaseDate), MONTH(ReleaseDate)` at the start should do it, you wouldn't need `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

Simething like This  : 
`select convert(varchar(50),YEAR(date)) +'/'+convert (varchar(50), MONTH(date)) ,Name , COUNT( Name) ,[DATE] from  table1
group by convert(varchar(50),YEAR(date)) +'/'+convert (varchar(50), MONTH(date)) ,Name,[date]
order by [Date] Desc`